# Using "podman start" with a command?

Tags: podman

I have a container, and I need to run systemd inside of it like this,

```
podman run -ti centos:7 /sbin/init
```

Now let's say I make some modifications in that container and then I exit that container thereby stopping it. Now it has a status of `Exited`. However, if I wish to jump back in that container I can with `podman start`. The only problem with this, is `podman start` does not give the ability to launch a specific program in that container (like /sbin/init). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podman stores the commands it used to launch the container, and restarting it will relaunch it with the same command. You can use `podman config --cmd` to change that command.

If you want to see the init sequence or the result of whatever command you're using **do not forget to `-a` attach** when running `podman start`.